# ListFragment not populating

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment

I'm still working on my learning activity dealing with loading contacts into a listfragment.  The entire app builds and I get no force closes, but my list fragment does not show the contacts list. I'm using examples from around the web so I'm sure that there is some incompatibility somewhere.  Any help is appreciated as I am learning and trying to figure things out on the go.

Below is my ContactListFragment which *should* display the list of contacts:

```
public class ContactListFragment extends ListFragment {
    private ContactAdapter mAdapter;
    private List<ContactItem> contactItemList = new LinkedList<ContactItem>();

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public boolean taskRun = false;
    long currentID = 0;
    long currentContactID = 0;
    public ContactListFragment() {}
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
        if(!taskRun){
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ListContactTask task= new ListContactTask(getActivity(),ft);
            task.execute(); 

        }
        taskRun = true;
        mAdapter = new ContactAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.lvmain,R.id.key, contactItemList);
        mAdapter .setInflater(mInflater);
        mAdapter.setLayout(R.layout.contact_card);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        ListView listView = getListView();
        getListView().invalidate();

    }

    public void setDataList( List<ContactItem> list) {  
        Activity act = getActivity();
        this.contactItemList = list;
        if(act != null) {
            mAdapter = new ContactAdapter(act, R.layout.lvmain,R.id.key, list);
            mAdapter .setInflater(mInflater);
            mAdapter.setLayout(R.layout.contact_card);
            setListAdapter(mAdapter );
            getListView().invalidate();

        }
    }
}
class ContactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ContactItem> {

       private static String TAG = ContactAdapter.class.getName();
       private LayoutInflater inflator = null;
       List<ContactItem> pairList = null;
       private int layout;
       public ContactAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                int textViewResourceId, List<ContactItem> objects) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
            this.pairList = objects;
        }

        public void setInflater(LayoutInflater mInflater) {
            this.inflator = mInflater;
        }
        public void setLayout(int layout){
            this.layout = layout;

        }

        /**
         * Make a view to hold each row.
         * 
         * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getView(int, android.view.View,
         *      android.view.ViewGroup)
         */
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            try {
                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = this.inflator.inflate(
                            layout, null);
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.key = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.key);
                    holder.value = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.value);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                }else {
                     holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }
                ContactItem pair = (ContactItem) getItem(position);
                String key = pair.mDisplayName;
                String value = pair.mPhone;

                holder.key.setText(key);
                holder.value.setText(value);
                Log.i("pairing", "happened");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.toString(), e);
            }
            return convertView;
        }

        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView key;
            TextView value;
        }

        public Filter getFilter() {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 1;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return pairList.size();
        }

        public ContactItem getItem(int position) {
            return (ContactItem) super.getItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return super.getItemViewType(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return super.getViewTypeCount();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return super.isEmpty();
        }
    }
```

This is a list contact task (from an example I am using).  I commented out the onPostExecute as it was causing me errors, so I am guessing that this is my issue.  The thing is I am not sure how to incorporate a receiver for the onPostExecute in my ContactListFragment.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Data;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;
import android.util.Log;

public class ListContactTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<ContactItem>> {
    private FragmentTransaction ft;
    private Activity activity;
    public ListContactTask(Activity activity, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.ft = ft;
    }

    public ListContactTask() {
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    protected List<ContactItem> doInBackground(Void... params) {
         Cursor c = activity.getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI,
                  new String[] {Data._ID, Data.DISPLAY_NAME,Phone.NUMBER, Data.CONTACT_ID,Phone.TYPE, Phone.LABEL},
                  Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'",
                  null, 
                  Data.DISPLAY_NAME);

        int count = c.getCount();
        boolean b = c.moveToFirst();
        String[] columnNames = c.getColumnNames();
        int displayNameColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("display_name");
        int idColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("_id");
        //int contactIdColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("contact_id");
        int col2Index = c.getColumnIndex(columnNames[2]);
        int col3Index = c.getColumnIndex(columnNames[3]);
        int col4Index = c.getColumnIndex(columnNames[4]);

        List<ContactItem> contactItemList = new LinkedList<ContactItem>();
        for(int i = 0; i < count ; i ++) {
            String displayName = c.getString(displayNameColIndex);
            String phoneNumber = c.getString(col2Index);
            int contactId = c.getInt(col3Index);
            String phoneType = c.getString(col4Index);

            long _id = c.getLong(idColIndex);
            ContactItem contactItem = new ContactItem();
            contactItem.mId= _id;
            contactItem.mContactId = contactId;
            contactItem.mDisplayName = displayName;
            contactItem.mPhone = phoneNumber;
            contactItemList.add(contactItem);
            boolean b2 = c.moveToNext();
        }
        c.close();
        return contactItemList;
    }
/*
    protected void onPostExecute(List<ContactItem> result) {  
        ((MainActivity)activity).addContactListFragment(ft, result);

    } 
*/
}
```

Here is my layout files as well:

Contact_card.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffe6e6e6" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/card_background"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contactImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_contact"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="3dip" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/key"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/contactImage"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/contactImage"
            android:text="TestNameHere"
            android:textColor="@color/card_text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/contact_name"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/value"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/key"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/contactImage"
            android:text="800-867-5309"
            android:textColor="@color/card_text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/contact_phone"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

lvmain.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="#00000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope this all makes sense, and I am not just rambling down a wrong path.

EDIT:

Helps to include my MainActivity as well:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Quick Actions", "Contacts", "Apps" };


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_search) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

}
```

EDIT 2:
 I have made the modifications noted below, but now am receiving this error:

```
The method setDataList(List<ContactItem>) in the type ContactListFragment is not applicable for the arguments ()
```

Here is my updated ListContact.java:

```
import com.nmiltner.slidedialer.free.data.ContactItem;
import com.nmiltner.slidedialer.free.ContactListFragment;
import com.nmiltner.slidedialer.free.MainActivity;

public class ListContactTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<ContactItem>> {
    private FragmentTransaction ft;
    private Activity activity;
    public ListContactTask(Activity activity, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.ft = ft;
    }

    public ListContactTask() {
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    protected List<ContactItem> doInBackground(Void... params) {
         Cursor c = activity.getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI,
                  new String[] {Data._ID, Data.DISPLAY_NAME,Phone.NUMBER, Data.CONTACT_ID,Phone.TYPE, Phone.LABEL},
                  Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'",
                  null, 
                  Data.DISPLAY_NAME);

        int count = c.getCount();
        boolean b = c.moveToFirst();
        String[] columnNames = c.getColumnNames();
        int displayNameColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("display_name");
        int idColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("_id");
        //int contactIdColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("contact_id");
        int col2Index = c.getColumnIndex(columnNames[2]);
        int col3Index = c.getColumnIndex(columnNames[3]);
        int col4Index = c.getColumnIndex(columnNames[4]);

        List<ContactItem> contactItemList = new LinkedList<ContactItem>();
        for(int i = 0; i < count ; i ++) {
            String displayName = c.getString(displayNameColIndex);
            String phoneNumber = c.getString(col2Index);
            int contactId = c.getInt(col3Index);
            String phoneType = c.getString(col4Index);

            long _id = c.getLong(idColIndex);
            ContactItem contactItem = new ContactItem();
            contactItem.mId= _id;
            contactItem.mContactId = contactId;
            contactItem.mDisplayName = displayName;
            contactItem.mPhone = phoneNumber;
            contactItemList.add(contactItem);
            boolean b2 = c.moveToNext();
        }
        c.close();
        return contactItemList;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(List<ContactItem> result) {  
        ContactListFragment.setDataList();

    } 

}
```

and my ContactListFragment:

```
public class ContactListFragment extends ListFragment {
    private ContactAdapter mAdapter;
    private List<ContactItem> contactItemList = new LinkedList<ContactItem>();

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public boolean taskRun = false;
    long currentID = 0;
    long currentContactID = 0;
    public ContactListFragment() {}
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
        if(!taskRun){
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ListContactTask task= new ListContactTask(getActivity(),ft);
            task.execute(); 

        }
        taskRun = true;
        mAdapter = new ContactAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.lvmain,R.id.key, contactItemList);
        mAdapter .setInflater(mInflater);
        mAdapter.setLayout(R.layout.contact_card);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        ListView listView = getListView();
        getListView().invalidate();

    }

    public void setDataList( List<ContactItem> list) {  
        Activity act = getActivity();
        this.contactItemList = list;
        if(act != null) {
            mAdapter = new ContactAdapter(act, R.layout.lvmain,R.id.key, list);
            mAdapter .setInflater(mInflater);
            mAdapter.setLayout(R.layout.contact_card);
            setListAdapter(mAdapter );
            getListView().invalidate();

        }
    }
}
class ContactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ContactItem> {

       private static String TAG = ContactAdapter.class.getName();
       private LayoutInflater inflator = null;
       List<ContactItem> pairList = null;
       private int layout;
       public ContactAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                int textViewResourceId, List<ContactItem> objects) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
            this.pairList = objects;
        }

        public void setInflater(LayoutInflater mInflater) {
            this.inflator = mInflater;
        }
        public void setLayout(int layout){
            this.layout = layout;

        }

        /**
         * Make a view to hold each row.
         * 
         * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getView(int, android.view.View,
         *      android.view.ViewGroup)
         */
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            try {
                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = this.inflator.inflate(
                            layout, null);
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.key = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.key);
                    holder.value = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.value);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                }else {
                     holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }
                ContactItem pair = (ContactItem) getItem(position);
                String key = pair.mDisplayName;
                String value = pair.mPhone;

                holder.key.setText(key);
                holder.value.setText(value);
                Log.i("pairing", "happened");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.toString(), e);
            }
            return convertView;
        }

        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView key;
            TextView value;
        }

        public Filter getFilter() {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 1;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return pairList.size();
        }

        public ContactItem getItem(int position) {
            return (ContactItem) super.getItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return super.getItemViewType(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return super.getViewTypeCount();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return super.isEmpty();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `AsyncTask` probably hasn't finished working before you've called `ContactListFragment.setListAdapter()`, so its probably empty in the first place. Handle your UI changes (call `ContactListFragment.setDataList()`) in your `AsyncTask.onPostExecute()` method so you can ensure that the `AsyncTask` is complete and the adapter will be populated.

Edit: if you want a specific `AsyncTask.onPostExecute()`, you can override it like so in `ContactListFragment`:

```
ListContactTask task = new ListContactTask () {
    protected void onPostExecute(List<ContactItem> result) {
        // do specific stuff here, eg:
        ContactListFragment.this.setDataList(result);
    }
};
// Do other stuff
```

Comment: I haven't had much time to get back into it. I will tonight though, and will respond.

Comment: the above solution doesn't seem to be working for me @Ani Fichadia. I am not even intelligent enough to explain what is going on either.  The error I am getting is "The method setDataList(List<ContactItem>) in the type ContactListFragment is not applicable for the arguments ()"  I am not even sure what that means, as I said this is a learning experience for me.  Perhaps I need to look at another method of populating the list of contacts in my ListFragment

Comment: Can you post your updated code? Looks like the argument are incorrect.

Comment: I've edited the OP with my updated classes. Thanks in advance for the help @Ani Fichadia.